# How do I check how many entries there are within a nested list and then remove all other values other than the last 3 for each item?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, sublist

I have a list of fruit:

```
fruit = [[['apples', '2'], ['apples', '7']], [['banana','5'], ['banana','6'], ['banana','3'], ['banana','9'], ['banana','1']], [['grapes','10'], ['grapes','0'], ['grapes','7']]]
```

As you can see on my shopping list, it is a nested list where items that are the same are grouped together within a list. What I want to do is:

1. Check how many entries there are for each fruit
2. If the number of entries for the fruit is 3 or less, leave it as it is
3. If the number of entries for the fruit is more than 3, remove entries for that fruit (starting from `fruit[x][0]` for that fruit) until the last three entries of the fruits remain. For example, this would be done to the `'banana'`'s for the above list as the number of entries for `'banana'` is 5 and so first two entries (`['banana','5'], ['banana','6']`) would be removed and `['banana','3'], ['banana','9'], ['banana','1']` would remain.

If this is done correctly, the resultant code would be:

```
fruit = [[['apples', '2'], ['apples', '7']], [['banana','3'], ['banana','9'], ['banana','1']], [['grapes','10'], ['grapes','0'], ['grapes','7']]]
```

How can I do this? I have tried checking the number of entries by using a `for` loop but I didn't know how to remove things within the list.

Thanks:)

Comment: So I'm guessing you want to know how to remove an item from the list? Try ls.remove(ls[i]) where i is the index of the element you want to remove and ls is the list.

Comment: Thanks but I think my problem was that I didn't know how to do them both at the same time and make them work like how I wanted to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through the main list, replacing each item list with its last three objects (which will do nothing to lists that are already shorter than or equal to 3 objects):

```
for i in range(len(fruit)):
    fruit[i] = fruit[i][-3:]
```

Or, in comprehension form:

```
fruit = [f[-3:] for f in fruit]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension with an `if`/`else` statement as follows:

```
fruits = [[['apples', '2'], ['apples', '7']], [['banana','5'], ['banana','6'], ['banana','3'], ['banana','9'], ['banana','1']], [['grapes','10'], ['grapes','0'], ['grapes','7']]]

answer = [fruit if len(fruit) <= 3 else fruit[-3:] for fruit in fruits]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[[['apples', '2'], ['apples', '7']],
 [['banana', '3'], ['banana', '9'], ['banana', '1']],
 [['grapes', '10'], ['grapes', '0'], ['grapes', '7']]]
```